# Check whether url from api data contain a particular string

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have my JSON data from API stored in map now one of its data is named with URL and contains URL of the sites I have to check whether the URL contains a particular string or not so that I can apply different styling to the div on HTML

```
let x = `${ values.url }`;
      if (x.contains("codeforces")) {
        console.log("Yes");
      }
```

I am getting error while using this:

[image: console error]

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `includes` function. There is no function called `contains`

```
let x = values.url;
  if (x.includes("codeforces")) {
    console.log("Yes");
  }
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Yes I was able to console log thank you but now I have a issue with it

let x = `${values.url}`;
      if (x.includes("codechef")) {
        // console.log("Yes");
        document
          .getElementById("all_contest")
          .setAttribute("style", 'backgroundColor:red');
      }
I am using this to change bg color of the div but getting error that

contest.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')
    at contest.js:17:11
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at contest.js:7:26